# How to refer to related table in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

Currently in seeds.rb I have such code:

```
Mission.create({ name: "Web Platform", status_id: 3});

# Statuses
Status.create({ name: "active"})
Status.create({ name: "complete"})
Status.create({ name: "future"})
```

It seems very wrong (because from outside this status_id looks like a magic number without meaning, and because depends on order (or setting ids manually)) but I can't find: how it would be better to do?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html should answer a lot of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to assign your statuses to variables, and then use them.

```
# Statuses
active   = Status.create({ name: "active"})
complete = Status.create({ name: "complete"})
future   = Status.create({ name: "future"})

Mission.create({ name: "Web Platform", status_id: future.id});
```

Comment: You should even be okay with `status: future` and let the ORM mess with `id`s.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your Mission `has_one :status` and Status `belongs_to :mission`

Something like this:

```
Status.create(name: 'active')
# Same for complete and future

mission = Mission.build(name: 'Web Platform')
mission.status = Status.where(name: 'future').first
mission.save
```

Or even better, improve your model Status class

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.status_active
        where(name: 'active').first_or_create
    end

    def self.status_complete
        where(name: 'complete').first_or_create
    end
    # Etc...
end
```

And then you can do

```
mission = Mission.build(name: 'Web Platform')
mission.status = Status.status_future
mission.save!
```

Without any need to even create the status manually (thanks to **Mike Manfrin** suggestion)

Comment: This is a better answer than mine. This is a much, much better style. You could even do `first_or_create` to negate any need for seeding the data in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Mission has_one :status

```
mission = Mission.create name: "Web Platform"
mission.status.create name: "active"
```

then you can edit status by typing:

```
mission.status.update_attributes name: "future"
```